# Alternative to fs.readFileSync()

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, webpack

I'm importing a css file into my npm module with [Insert-css](https://github.com/substack/insert-css) but i get an error.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var inserCss = require('insert-css');
var css = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '../css/file.css');
insertCss(css);
```

and the error I'm getting is

"Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function"

Is there any alternative for fs.readFileSync? maybe npm module "Path"?

Comment: Have you npm install fs ?

Comment: @KeyurSakaria why `npm install fs`, its core module comes with node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created [Node-Cheat](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/blob/master/files/read_file.js) for sync and async file reading see following working code:

```
//------------------------------------------------------
//fs module to read file in sync and async way
//Web Link=> https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/blob/master/files/read_file.js
//------------------------------------------------------


var fs = require('fs'),
    filePath = './sample_files/sample_css.css';

// this for async way
/*fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
});*/

//this is sync way
var css = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
console.log(css);
```

Node Cheat Available at [read_file](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/blob/master/files/read_file.js) with sample css file.

Comment: I'm having similar problem with `fs`. Do you mind check it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608118/uncaught-typeerror-fs-readfilesync-is-not-a-function